# Accessing a function/state of a component in a wrapping HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a component A (extends React.component) and it is wrapped with a higher order component B.

In component B's methods, I need to setState for A, or call a function in A (so that it can do the setState) - how is this generally done?

I can paste actual code here, but I thought it may complicate matters if there are standard ways of handling this situation.

Edit: here's the code - isOpen needs to change for the Modal to close, and it needs to change in handleSubmit....

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { withFormik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import Yup from 'yup';

// first part of Formik integration
const formikEnhancer = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues(props) {
    return {
      personName: props.email || '',
      personSurname: props.surname || '',
      personCongregation: props.congregation || ''
    }
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    personName: Yup.string().required().min(1),
    personSurname: Yup.string().required().min(2),
    personCongregation: Yup.string().required().min(8)
  }),
  handleSubmit(values, {props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}) {
    submitNewPerson(values, {resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting});
    props.testCall;
  }
});

function submitNewPerson(v, {resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}) {
  //e.preventDefault();

  congregations = [];
  congregations.push(v.personCongregation);

  const peep = {
    name: v.personName,
    surname: v.personSurname,
    congregations: congregations//,
    //startDate: Number(e.target.componentStartDate.value),
    //endDate: Number(e.target.componentEndDate.value)
  };
    // do the db insert here and check for errors
    setSubmitting(false);
  });
};

class AddPerson extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: undefined,
      isOpen: false
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Modal.setAppElement('body');
  }

  renderCong() {
    // this just maps out a list of select options
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="button" onClick={()=> this.setState({isOpen:true, error:undefined})}>+ Add Person</button>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen} contentLabel="Add Person"
          className = "boxed-view__box" overlayClassName="boxed-view boxed-view--modal">
          <Form className="boxed-view__form">
            <div>
              <Field type="text" name="personName" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Field type="text" name="personSurname" placeholder="Surname" />
            </div>
            <div>
             <Field component="select" name="personCongregation" value={this.state.cong}>
                <option key="0" value="">- Select Option -</option>
                {this.renderCong()}
              </Field>
            </div>
            <button disabled={this.props.isSubmitting} className="button">Add Person</button>
            <button disabled={this.props.isSubmitting} type="button" className="button button--secondary" onClick={
              ()=> {
                this.props.resetForm();
                this.setState({isOpen:false});
              }}>Cancel</button>
          </Form>

        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  };
};
```

Comment: In an high order component, you should never needs to use set state on your wrapped component.
The only way to communicate with your wrapped component is to use `props` Could you describe a little more your functionnal use case ?

Comment: B should not know about A's state, A should present an interface to be updated that B can use, this can be done by exposing props that B can update, you can add a `componentWillReceiveProps` method to A to update the state accordingly given the received props.

Comment: Thanks - helpful start. So the HOC (B) is Formik, which deals with validation and submission of forms. In my Component (A) I open a model by changing state to display the form. Then Formik (B) has a handleSubmit method that triggers when (A) is submitted. If the submission is successful I need to close the modal by changing state - if it is false I need to display an error by changing state.

Comment: For this you should have the submission handled by the form's parent component, which can (a) trigger on an onSubmit callback from your form component, and (b) hold the success/failure state and pass that back down as a prop to be displayed.

Comment: Then I think that the state should be handled inside B as it is the one handling form submission results, you could have a `modalOpen` and `hasError` attributes in your B state that you can update there and then send as props to A so that it can update its own state and hide/show the modal as well as the error.

Comment: Ok that sounds good - how do I send those attributes in B to A as props? mapValuesToProps? Sorry, that's a noob question, but I am a noob!

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are in control of component B, this isn't really possible. Some popular HOCs (like `connect` in react-redux) have a mechanism that allows you to expose the wrapped component A, but this isn't true in general.

It's generally better not to do this at all. If the state of a component needs to be changed from the outside, it should be passed in as a prop and the "source of truth" should be your model or viewmodel. If you're using something like redux, try moving your component state into redux state, and instead of calling setState, use a redux action/reducer combo to update it.

Another way is to move the state up one level so that it's passed in as a prop from another component (the parent), and then have the logic in that parent, although this is much less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you send props to the component and then you handle those props with a function, that in this case sets the state with stuff, example:

```
class B extends React.Component{

   render(){
       <A toUpdateState={this.state.valueB} />
   }
}

class A extends React.Component{

   updateState(){
       this.setState({
           ...this.state,
           valueA: this.props.toUpdateState
       })
   }

   render(){...}
}
```

If you trigger the state in the B component the A component will receive the info.

There are other ways to do this but without the code its hard to give you a diferent solution.

Comment: Nothing in the code you are presenting is making sure that `updateState` gets called when A receives new props, please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - added my own onClick handler (instead of allowing Formik to call its handleSubmit method) - my handler then calls Formik's handleSubmit and then changes state depending on return value﻿